# problem installing orocos_toolchain in ros melodic

Tags: ros

I have some problems following the tutorial "http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutori...". I have installed ROS Melodic and i want to use an slave ethercat like the "IO rack: EtherCAT Couper, 8 DI, & 8DO (all Beckhoff)" but different brand (Omron), and when i try to follow the step 1: Install OROCOS toolchain for ROS it return a error when i follow the tutorial "http://wiki.ros.org/orocos_toolchain" and execute the command "rosdep install orocos_toolchain" the error is the next: ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query Missing resource orocos_toolchain.

I use ROS 1 Distro: melodic SO: Ubuntu 18:04

Someone can i help me, please. I was searching another ways to install OROCOS toolchain but i didn't have success.

Comment: Please use correct upper case letters.

Comment: You cut off the first link, if you wanted us to use it.

Comment: http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Simple_EtherCAT_Network_IO sorry but I didn't see that the link was cut. buhtz What upper case letters?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the readily available documentation for installing / using Orocos is out of date. For example, that page you were at is (at timeof writing) 6 years old, for an end-of-life distro.

The up-to-date info is on their [github](https://github.com/orocos/rtt_ros_integration/tree/toolchain-2.9) and [website](https://www.orocos.org/wiki/orocos/toolchain/getting-started) (The website, for you right now, is probably less useful, but [this page](https://www.orocos.org/wiki/upgrading-toolchain-2x-toolchain-28x) still is). Respectively, you should now install that fat stack as `sudo apt install ros-melodic-rtt-ros-integration`, aka install from binary sources. Make sure to pay careful attention to [Building ROS-Based Orocos Components](https://github.com/orocos/rtt_ros_integration/tree/toolchain-2.9#building-ros-based-orocos-components), because they have their own system which changes the CMake process. There's also other packages that they/others keep from other stacks, you can see the whole list by trying to autocomplete `apt install ros-melodic-rtt-`